# How to detect object collision for this JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, object, collision

Trying to put together a small game for practice and I came across a issue.  The point is to catch the goblin but I don't know how to make the game detect that player has hit the goblin.

So far you can only detect touched if your position Y and X matches with the enemies axis.  How can I either increase the width for both or a better way of detecting touch.

try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/acbkk7cs/4/

Style:

```
#map{
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 510px;
        width: 510px;
        background-image:url(background.png);

    } 

    .character{
        background-image:url(character.png);
        z-index:1;
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        left: 150px;
        height: 32px;
        width: 33px;
    }

    .monster{
        background-image:url(monster.png);

        position: relative;
        height: 32px;
        width: 30px;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            var char = { 

                player : $(".character"),
                x: 150,
                y: 150

            };

            var monster = {

                npc : $(".monster"),
                x: 100,
                y: 100
            };

            var keypush = {};


        $(document).on("keydown keyup", function(e){

            var keyN = e.which;
            keypush[keyN] = e.type === "keydown";


        });





    function moveCharacter(){

        if (keypush[37]) char.x -=2;
        if (keypush[38]) char.y -=2;
        if (keypush[39]) char.x +=2;
        if (keypush[40]) char.y +=2;

        char.player.css({transform:"translate3D("+ char.x +"px, "+ char.y +"px, 0)"});
        monster.npc.css({transform:"translate3D("+ monster.x +"px, "+ monster.y +"px, 0)"});


        var playerPosX = char.player.position().top;
        var monsterPosX = monster.npc.position().top;

        var playerPosY = char.player.position().left;
        var monsterPosY = monster.npc.position().left;


        if ( playerPosX === monsterPosX
            && playerPosY === monsterPosY 
           ){

            document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML="Touched"; 

        } else {

            document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML="Off";
        }




//backend logs

 console.log(char.x);            
    }






        (function engine(){
        moveCharacter();
        window.requestAnimationFrame(engine);
    }());    

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "map">
        <div class = "character">

        </div>
        <div class = "monster">
            <p id = "pos" style = "color:yellow;font-  weight:bold;position:relative;left:5px;font-size:20px;">Position: </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way is to calculate the distance between the character and the monster: [fiddle using circle collision](https://jsfiddle.net/acbkk7cs/6/).

```
    var dx = playerPosX - monsterPosX,
        dy = playerPosY - monsterPosY,
        touchDistance = 30; 

    if ( Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy ) < touchDistance )           
       document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML="Touched";                
    else
       document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML="Off";
```

Here, I eyeballed the `touchDistance`, but it's actual value should be the sum of the radius of the player sprite and the radius of the monster sprite. This works best if they are circles:

```
/**
 * (ax,ay) and (bx,by) are the center positions, and ar, br their radii.
 */
function circleCollision( ax, ay, ar, bx, by, br ) {
    return Math.sqrt( (ax-bx)*(ax-bx) + (ay-by)*(ay-by) ) <= ar + br;
}
```

A second common way to determine collision is to use 'bounding boxes', or in this case, rectangles/squares: [Fiddle using rectangle collision](https://jsfiddle.net/acbkk7cs/7/).

```
function rectangleCollision( pLeft, pTop, pRight, pBottom, mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom ) {
  return
     ( (pLeft   >= mLeft && pLeft   < mRight ) || (pRight >= mLeft && pRight < mRight ) )
  && ( (pBottom >= mTop  && pBottom < mBottom) || (pTop   >= mTop  && pTop   < mBottom) )
}
```

Comment: Once is plenty. Thank you! ;-)

Comment: @OsuCommunity, If it matters to you, the game designer, the touch distance isn't a constant. You'll need to take into account that your characters are essentially squares, and the corners can overlap even with the center points being outside the touch distance. In the updated fiddle, I can easily get the corners to overlap and still display "Off".

Comment: One way to avoid corner overlap is to define corner points for each character relative to its center point. If a monster corner point is ever closer the to man center than the man's corner point, they touched.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll look into them.